# React synthetic event: OnMouseEnter infinite trigger

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I'm currently working on the accessibility of a React component.

The component is fairly simple... It should provide a list of results based on a search term, providing navigation using up/down/tab/shift+tab, and of course, cursor.

The index in which keyboard navigation starts is 0, if no item is hovered on the list of results, or n, if n is the index of the hovered item.

Therefore, the results is an array of objects, and those objects have a "active" boolean property, which mimics the hover status.

As part of this implementation I'm using `OnMouseEnter` event, which triggers a function that will update the results array state, setting all active properties to false, unless the one with the hovered index.

The problem is that this event is being triggered infinitely. And no, I'm not directly calling the function on the event, I'm calling it inside an arrow function, something like:

```
<li OnMouseEnter={() => handleMouseEnter(index)}>
```

I don't have access to the code atm, but I think the explanation above is enough to give context.

Why is OnMouseEnter triggering infinite times? To complete the implementation I need it to trigger only when cursor enters the boundaries of those list item elements.

Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The state is being updated inside the `handleMouseEnter`. This state update triggers react re-rendering, which in turn triggers the `OnMouseEnter` event causing infinite loop.

Comment: To avoid this infinite loop, use the `useRef` hook to create a reference to the list item element and attach the event listener to that reference instead of attaching it directly to the li. This'll ensure that the event listener is only attached once and not re-attached on each re-render.

Comment: @JishanShaikh perfect makes so much sense :)

Comment: Can you implement this, or I can try implementing the new `handleMouseEnter` function?

Comment: I can do it from here. Thanks for the tip!